Install torch/tensorflow/transformers with poetry
I've spent hours reading topics/issues on github about how to install those 3 packages with poetry and everytime the module install but when I run my notebook, I get this:
[WinError 126] Specified module can't be found

I installed other package without any problems, I managed to make transformers install & run (do not ask me how, it works randomly) but I need at least torch to run my project.
Any idea how to fix it/install properly those packages ?
I tried pretty much everything, exiting/entering the shell before install, running all poetry install/build/update commands, rebooting after install, using poetry run to install it through pip install, installing transformers by installing sentence-transformers (so as a dependencies of another package)
The packages are often installed but can not be found/located when running the project, but other package as geopandas, numpy, pandas, bs4 did not encounter any of those problems and are sitll working

Can you please provide more details? eg what's in your pyproject.tolm and steps to reproduce

pyproject.toml is the default one, I just installed a few package that I need with "poetry add". I think I installed pandas, tqdm, geopandas, bs4, sklearn, matplotlib and obviously jupyter to run notebooks.
I installed python through the official download link for windows (not the store), poetry was installed following the official tutorial so I don't know what is wrong
It's a fresh install all last version
